# Android stopped connecting to computers via USB

Tags: android

suddenly it started giving me no notification any time i plug it into any PC. I've used different USB cables,turned on my USB debugging mode,restored the factory settings, updated the phone software. I don't know what else to do. I really need help here

Comment: You got the Driver installedon your PC?

Comment: 1) Go to device manager, and see is your phone getting connected as an 'unknown device'?
If not, 
2) What android version you have? Do you have 'Revoke USB debugging authorizations' as an option right below 'USB debugging' check box? Try to click that and connect your phone again.

Comment: No i don't. the android version is 4.4.2

Comment: better ask here http://android.stackexchange.com/ - here is about coding

Answer (score 1):

Browse to your sdk on studio terminal and type `adb devices` and check if it shows.
If not try `adb killall-server` and `adb start-server` otherwise try updating usb driver for your phone

Comment: how do i update my usb drivver

Comment: Right click on My computer->`Manage` and then locate your device and and there you will find the options to update or you may try `AdbDriverInstaller`

Comment: I'm not seeing the phone at all. i've searched the whole of device manager

Comment: Then,there might be some other problem.A device connected to pc will be shown in the device manager.check it again

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Samsung Phone, try installing Samsung Kies on your PC. That should include all drivers.

Comment: Thanks but it's not an android phone

Comment: I think you meant *Samsung phone*  in your above comment, not "Android phone". Else the question title is misleading ;)

Comment: sorry. i meant to say it is not a samsung phone